# Trouble installing r2ghidra

Tags: ghidra, radare2

I am using a MacBook with OS Ventura 13.3 and trying to install the r2ghidra plug-in through the command `r2pm -ci r2ghidra` but it fails with the following error:
[image: Terminal output of failed r2ghidra installation]

I have tried various fixes such as reinstalling radare2 both by running brew install radare2 and per the instruction on the radare2 github, i.e.

```
git clone https://github.com/radareorg/radare2
radare2/sys/install.sh
```

Does anyone know how I could resolve this issue and download r2ghidra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found that running

```
brew install pkg-config
```

worked even though I already had pkgconfig.